# How to call tag message when conditions violated

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have such tag

`<p:message for="Widget" id="message" showDetail="false"
showSummary="true" display="text"
style="margin-top:5px; color:red" styleClass="bold" />`

and conditions

`if (itemStringList.size() >= 3) {error();}`

How can I display this message when this conditions violated.

Comment: From your managedBean `MyUtil.addWarnMessage("ERROR");
                    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(":message");`

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what do you mean "MyUtil" (it must be variable, or specific component?) and I need to create  method MyUtil.addWarnMessage(String); or this component has it as own method?

Comment: `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "Warning!", "Watch out for PrimeFaces."));` you can look to [Primefaces messages](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/message/messages.xhtml)